# How to create exported function aliases for type checking based on different arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, tsc

I have this:

```
export const set = (k: LocalStorageKeys.CP_EMAIL, v: string) => void;
export const set = (k: LocalStorageKeys.CP_USER_ID, v: string) => void;
export const set = (k: LocalStorageKeys.CP_USER, v: User) => void;

export const set = (k: LocalStorageKeys, v: any) : void => {
  return localStorage.setItem(k, JSON.stringify(v));
};
```

but `tsc` doesn't like it, it says set is redeclared in the block:

> TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'set'.

is there a way to do what I am trying to do? My goal is to type-check the set function and if a key is a certain key, expect a certain type for the second argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the TypeScript gitter channel, I got an answer:

[image]

Works very nicely, thanks!

Comment: Please edit this post to feature text instead of pictures of text.  See [this meta  post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for more info.

Comment: I can't I lost the original text unfortunately